# Validation Using jQuery and Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need `regular expression` for number started with 0 and the length of this number is 11

i find this regular expression for numbers but this is not for length and 0 at started

```
$('#myModal #transfer_charge_model_mob').keyup(function () {
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
            if (!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
                $('#myModal #transfer_charge_model_mob_lbl').text('please enter number');
                $(this).val('');
            }
            else {
                $('#myModal #transfer_charge_model_mob_lbl').text('');
            }
        });
```

Comment: /^0\d{10}$/ would be my first try but I see now that you use on keyup. Mine would be used on change or blur

Comment: @mplungjan This will be the best approach.  Because for each keyup the function will be executed.

Comment: @mplungjan Your comment answered this question :) so make this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without regex.

```
var x = $(this).val();
var y = x * 1;
if(!isNaN(y))
   if (x.charAt(0) === '0' && x.length == 11)
     //do whatever
```

Comment: The y=x*1 and isNaN() check if it was a number or not. a string multiply will create a NaN, and the 'is typing' part is handled by the keyup

Comment: but the z.length() not. And I believe it is z.length

Comment: actually you're right, it strips the leading zeroes. have to use x instead of z in that last bit - fixing

Answer (score 2):

You've overcomplicated your regex:

```
^0\d{10}$
```

is sufficent.

Comment: Great suggestion - identical to my comment

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't spotted your comment when I wrote this!

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer, seeing how popular it was

Note the on("change") rather than the keyup

```
$('#transfer_charge_model_mob').on("change",function () {
   var inputVal = $(this).val();
   var txt = /^0\d{10}$/.test(inputVal)?"":'please enter number';     
   $('#transfer_charge_model_mob_lbl').text(txt);
   if (txt) $(this).val('');
 });
```

For Keyup you might try

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LuyVn/)

```
$(function() {
  $('#transfer_charge_model_mob')
    .on("change",function () {
       var inputVal = $(this).val();
       var txt = /^0\d{10}$/.test(inputVal)?"":'please enter number';     
       $('#transfer_charge_model_mob_lbl').text(txt);
       //if (txt) $(this).val(''); // Very harsh if a typo
     })
  .on("keyup",function(e) {
     var val = $(this).val(); 
     var reg =  /[^0-9]/g;
     if (val.match(reg)) { 
         $(this).val(val.replace(reg,""));
     }
  });    
});
```

Comment: I like your .on("keyup"), restricting alphabets being entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /^0\d{10}$/;
console.log(reg.test("01111111111"));
```

Comment: Great suggestion - identical to my comment

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I'm sorry.  Once I saw this question I was trying in jsfiddle.  Once I got it, without loading your comments I posted as answer.  Later I saw your comments and replied.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! Great to see your answer :).